# how to create SharePoint 2013 add-in?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2015

I am creating SharePoint add-in using visual studio community 2015, but it is showing error:

> SharePoint server or SharePoint foundation is not installed on the
>   machine.

Can anyone help? Should I install SharePoint foundation 2013 externally?

Comment: Just an FYI, Visual Studio 2015's version number is 14, and SharePoint 2013 is 15(16 for SPO), so I updated your question to use the years instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are u sure you have correct version of office developer tools installed? Try uninstalling office developer tools and reinstall from this location http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2015

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an Office 365 SharePoint site? If yes, did you use its URL when creating the project, on that screen:?

[image: Visual Studio Create SharePoint App screen]

Instead of your workstation name, you need to enter the URL of a real SharePoint site (either an Office 365 developer site -create one by following the link in the dialog, or an on-premises SharePoint farm).